# Android Nexus 6 Camera ignoring EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY

Tags: android, android-camera

I am calling the Camera on Nexus 6 like this:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); // Low Quality
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(currentPath));
startActivityForResult(videoIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

But no matter what I set the value of `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` to be it always take a high quality video (a 5 second video is always about ~8 MB)

Other devices and camera apps work as expected, it only started to happen I think with the upgrade to Android 6.0.

I have tried the different values in CamcorderProfile too, and they don't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> Other devices and camera apps work as expected

There are thousands of Android device models and hundreds of camera apps. I suspect that you have not tried them all. `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` is a hint, not a command. You cannot rely upon any particular camera app, whether pre-installed or installed by a user, to honor that extra.

> I have tried the different values in CamcorderProfile too, and they don't make a difference.

`CamcorderProfile` is not used as part of `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`. If you are referring to using `MediaRecorder` directly, you might wish to open a separate Stack Overflow question, where you supply the code that you are using to configure the `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. So to guarantee capture low quality video (even on Nexus devices) there is no way around creating your own video activity? Is there some library you may suggest that has a camera activity built in?

Comment: @DevanshGupta: "So to guarantee capture low quality video (even on Nexus devices) there is no way around creating your own video activity?" -- correct. "Is there some library you may suggest that has a camera activity built in?" -- well, there is [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2). I do not know which others handle video; more seem to handle photos.